# Подсчет строк таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь подсчитать кол-во одинаковых полей сборной таблицы(из 2-х шт.).
Таблица uniform:
id|naim
Таблица uniform_use_time:
id|uniform_id|count|use_time

```
SELECT
      -- COUNT(uniform_use_time.uniform_id),
      uniform.naim,
      uniform_use_time.id,
      uniform_use_time.count,
      uniform_use_time.use_time
FROM uniform
INNER JOIN uniform_use_time ON uniform_use_time.uniform_id = uniform.id
-- GROUP BY uniform_use_time.uniform_id
```

Запрос дает результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать выборку, чтобы в результате был еще один столбец с количеством одинаковых строк в таблице uniform_use_time
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показывайте исходные данные в виде CREATE TABLE / INSERT INTO и желаемый результат на этих данных в виде таблицы. Фотографии не нужны.

Comment: что считать "одинаковой строкой"?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis пардон, не так выразился). Одинаковых uniform_id в таблице uniform_use_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить в виде подзапроса:

```
SELECT
uniform.naim,
u2.id,
u2.count,
u2.use_time,
(select count(uniform_id) from  uniform_use_time u1 where u1.uniform_id=u2.uniform_id) as cnt
FROM uniform_use_time u2
INNER JOIN uniform ON u2.uniform_id = uniform.id
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно